# Red5 Pause/Play/Rewind Live Stream

Tags: live, red5

Can some one tell me that how it is possible to rewind the **live stream** via RED5 Server.?
Is it possible or not.

Code Snippet may help.Reply soon.

Also. I know pause has to deal with the flash player but i want to know from which position stream starts playing(from runtime,where it was stopped).??

Awaiting Quick Response.

B/R

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot rewind a live stream. As how i understand the live stream is spreaded directly to all connected clients. The frames will not be saved at the server. So the server isnt able to "go back".

You need to record the stream if you want to be able to rewind.

If you pause the stream the last frame is frozen on your screen. The server continues the broadcast and you miss the frames which are broadcasted during that time. If you continue playing, then the next frame is the LIVE frame which is broadcasted at that time. You miss some frames.

Thats the nature of a live stream. It is "live"! If you pause or rewind it isnt live any more. Thats a recorded stream.

Answer (score 0):

Create custom application or modify existing one (for example oflaDemo).

Create server stream in your class in appStart():

```
private IServerStream serverStream;

... 
public boolean appStart( IScope app ) {
serverStream = StreamUtils.createServerStream( app , "MyOwnTVChannel" );
```

Add .flv files from /streams/ (oflaDemo example) to play:

```
serverStream.addItem( SimplePlayItem.build( "prometheus" , 0 , 20000 ) );
serverStream.addItem( SimplePlayItem.build( "someOthefFLVMovie" , 0 , 20000 ) );
```

20000 means 20 sec of playing - you can use `setRepeat(true)` after starting.

Start your stream:

```
serverStream.start();
```

Now, flash clients can watch your own TV channel with NetStream .play(  "MyOwnTVChannel" );
Remeber that if you do not set repeating, your channel will end in 40 sec in this example.